# Inline-block div losing right border

Tags: html, css

Using this code, I get two div side by side as I want. Except, the right border of the second div is missing. It seems like a size issue, as if the div was out of scope... How can I fix this?

I tried to add margins, nothing works...

```css
.wrapper {
   width: 100%; 
   white-space: nowrap;
   overflow: hidden;
}
    
.left { 
    width: 50%; 
    height:10px;
    border: 1px solid; 
    display: inline-block;     
}

.right {
    width: 50%; 
    height:10px; 
    border:1px solid; 
    display: inline-block;
    margin-left: -1px;
}
```

```html
<body style="margin-right: 50px">
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="left"></div><div class="right"></div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are looking for `box-sizing:border-box;`

```css
.wrapper {
       width: 100%; 
       white-space: nowrap;
       overflow: hidden;
    }
    
    .left { 
        width: 50%; 
        height:10px;
        border: 1px solid; 
        display: inline-block;
        box-sizing:border-box;
        border-right-width :0
    }
    .right {
        width: 50%; 
        height:10px; 
        border:1px solid; 
        display: inline-block;
         box-sizing:border-box;
    }
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
        <div class="left"></div><div class="right"></div>
      </div>
```

[box-sizing reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing)

> The box-sizing property is used to alter the default CSS box model used to calculate width and height of the elements. It is possible to use this property to emulate the behavior of browsers that do not correctly support the CSS box model specification.

The width and height properties include the content, the padding and border, but not the margin.

Answer (score 2):

Remove `overflow: hidden` from `.Wrapper` and your right border wall returns.

See the updated JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/8x2c4z16/2/

Comment: Additionally, the reason this happens is that `border` extends outside of elements, rather than sitting inside.

Comment: I wouldn't say it is a bug, this is how it is suppose to work. He told both divs to be 50%, then tells it to have 1px border on both sides. It is an oversight.

Comment: @LifeOfCoding bad phrasing on my part, you're correct. Easily overlooked though.

Answer (score 2):

You need to remove the overflow from wrapper, those borders adds 1px each left and right making it slightly more than 100% of the page, overflow cuts this off.

Both divs are 50% plus 1px on the left and right of both, making the total more than 100% of the page, and the wrapper overflow cuts this off.

Answer (score -2):

Just set your widths to 48% for the left and right classes

Comment: I don't think it's a good way to fix it, it seems a hackish way to achieve it.

Comment: 50% X 2 + 2 pixels is more than 100%, so something has to change, either container has to be larger than 100%, or the boxes need to be less than 50%..  not a hack, just extremely basic math

Comment: 2% of 100px may be 2px, but 2% of wider will not be 2px, have a look at the accepted answer, in my opinion, it's way better